# mingw. how to use static and dynamic linking both

Tags: c++, c, build, g++, mingw

lets make the simpliest application:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

result:
[image]

ok. it works.
lets add some SDL with default dynamic linking here!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

result:

[image]
works great. at stdout.txt we can see "puchuu"

lets change our makefile a little.
just group 2 object files to the static lib:

[image]

result:

[image]

Who is to blame?
Me or mingw developers?
is it clear to send to it's bug tracker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mingw is not to blame. With the (GNU) linker, static libraries have to be listed in the reverse dependency order.

`g++ -o program.exe libpuchuu.a -lSDL` will not work if something in libpuchuu.a depends on something in libSDL.

It should be `g++ -o program.exe  -lSDL libpuchuu.a`

If you have a cyclic dependency, you even have to list them twice. Consider e.g. libfoo.a depends on stuff in libbar.a ,and libbar.a depends on something in libfoo.a . You'll have to do: `g++ -o fooprogram libbar.a libfoo.a libbar.a`